# Underlined backslash IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, backslash

I am using a backslash as an escape character for a serialization format I am working on. I have it as a constant but IntelliJ is underlining it and highlighting it red. On hover it gives no error messages or any information as to why it does not like it.

[image]

What is the reason for this and how do I fix it?

Comment: It could be that you have an error in some syntax above/below it, and that is where it shows as an error.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean build?

Comment: Could it be that the char data type expects 1 character, not 2?

Comment: You can also try 'Invalidate Caches/Restart'. What version are you using?

Comment: @ham-sandwich No I just tried it with my IntelliJ 14 and it is not highlighted in red.

Comment: I have found the problem and answered the question. I should have realised it was something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ is smarter than I am and realised that I was using this character in a regular expression where 2 backslashes would be needed, however, IntelliJ also assumed that my puny mind could find the problem without giving me any information about it.

Comment: If this was indeed the problem, I would file a bug. The error is clearly reported on the wrong line.

Answer (score 2):

If it's being used as a regular expression, then the "\" **must be escaped**.

If you're escaping a "\" as "\" like traditional regular expressions require, then you also need to add two more `\\` for a total of `\\\\`.

This is because of the way Java interprets "\":

> In literal Java strings the backslash is an escape character. The
>   literal string "\" is a single backslash. In regular expressions, the
>   backslash is also an escape character. The regular expression \
>   matches a single backslash. This regular expression as a Java string,
>   becomes "\\". That's right: 4 backslashes to match a single one.
>
> The regex \w matches a word character. As a Java string, this is
>   written as "\w".
>
> The same backslash-mess occurs when providing replacement strings for
>   methods like String.replaceAll() as literal Java strings in your Java
>   code. In the replacement text, a dollar sign must be encoded as \$ and
>   a backslash as \ when you want to replace the regex match with an
>   actual dollar sign or backslash. **However, backslashes must also be
>   escaped in literal Java strings. So a single dollar sign in the
>   replacement text becomes "\$" when written as a literal Java string.
>   The single backslash becomes "\\". Right again: 4 backslashes to
>   insert a single one.**