# IntelliJ says "\\" (match on single backslash) is an illegal / unsupported escape sequence for Pattern.compile

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

The following pattern compile expression gives error in IntelliJ, even though the expression compiles and works well in Java (1.8):

```
Pattern.compile("\\", Pattern.LITERAL);
```

I´m using the following code to escape all occurences of `\` in a String with a double `\\`, like this:

```
private final static Pattern BACKSLASH_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\", Pattern.LITERAL);
private final static String BACKSLASH_REPLACE = Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\");

private String escapeBackslashes(final String s) { 
    return BACKSLASH_PATTERN.matcher(s).replaceAll(BACKSLASH_REPLACE);
}
```

When using `s.replace("\\", "\\\\")` IntelliJ does not complain, though, but I need to use the precompiled pattern for performance reasons (100s of MBs of data to process).

Might be a bug as in  [IntelliJ says \b (backspace) is an illegal escape sequence inside a string literal. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537321/intellij-says-b-backspace-is-an-illegal-escape-sequence-inside-a-string-liter) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underlined backslash IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618325/underlined-backslash-intellij)

Comment: It appears that IntelliJ does not take into account regex options when checking the regex argument.

Comment: This link will resolve your issue :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537321/intellij-says-b-backspace-is-an-illegal-escape-sequence-inside-a-string-liter

Comment: manfromnowhere: I do not want to disable the regexp checker in IntelliJ as the answer implies, also, I can not use the 'hack' by extracting the String variable and annotate it with the @org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language("TEXT") annotation, since my Java file does not have access to that annotation at runtime and as such the program would fail.

Comment: Found that is is already reported as a bug here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180708

Comment: you actually have two escapes: string-escape and regexp-escape. The string "\\" is a string with one character '\' which is not a valid regexp escape. use "\\\\" if you want to find one regexp-escapted '\'

Comment: k3b: 

This gives the correct result (but gives error in IntelliJ, not in Java):

    Pattern.compile("\\", Pattern.LITERAL).matcher("String with \ inside").replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\");

This does NOT work (OK in IntelliJ, but result is no replacement in string):

    Pattern.compile("\\\\", Pattern.LITERAL).matcher("String with \ inside").replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\");

Comment: v2019.1.3. I'm getting this error. Can be reproduced simply with `String a = "some\\thing";
 String[] b = a.split("\\"); `

Comment: v2020.1 something similar happens.  It's smart enough to not red-bang-squiggle on `s.split("\\.");` to split on a full stop / period / dot, but it fails if the code is checking a `char c;` for potential magic-ness, and then doing `"\\"+c` before splitting on that.  (A two-character delimiter string enables a fast path in `split`, so running it through Patter.quote() is avoided when viable.)

Answer (score 2):

You've got double escaping problems there. Java needs two backslashes \ in order for one backslash to appear in your string. Regex also has backslash escaping such that two backslashes in regex becomes one backslash for pattern matching.

Try escaping twice:

```
Pattern.compile("\\\\", Pattern.LITERAL);
```

This puts the pattern as '\' in regex which matches a single backspace.

Comment: And you don’t need `LITERAL`, since a (escaped) backslash has no special meaning in regex.